# Show Layered Navigation inside the product listing toolbar

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am building a custom module and I need to show the Layered Navigation inside the product listing toolbar. Can you please help on this
here is my catalog_category_view.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="George_CategoryNav::product/list/toolbar.phtml">

            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="product_list_toolbar" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

and here is my toolbar.phtml file

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation;
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getWidgetOptionsJson() ?>'>
        <div class="popup-button-wraper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>

        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>

        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code as above code looks fine.

Comment: @SukumarGorai This is the two file that required all other is registration and module.xml file

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>
```

Comment: @ Narayan Jat- I tried this before but it move the Layered Navigation below the toolbar, I need to move inside the toolbar